# Is "pronunciate" a word?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word, dictionaries, register

Is "pronunciate" a word? At first it doesn't seem to be, but why not? "Pronunciation" and "pronunciative" seem to be words, so it would seem natural that "pronunciate" would be.

After Googling, I found the following [here](http://theyuniversity.forumchitchat.com/post/enunciate-vs-pronunciate-6368656):

> "Pronunciate" is a word that isn't listed in most dictionaries; Dictionary.com does mention it, but it noted that "pronunciate" is used rarely. If you use it, most people will think that you meant to use "pronounce" but screwed up. Our tip is that you use "pronounce" instead of "pronunciate," unless you want to look like a person who uses "irregardless."

"Pronunciate" can also be found [on dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pronunciate):

> Definition: to declare or pronounce

Furthermore, I have heard the use of this word fairly often in speech. I have always assumed it was a word.

Despite all of this evidence, "pronunciate" seems to have very little usage (see dictionary.com link), and is not listed in most major dictionaries, including the Merriam-Webster dictionary. I have tried typing "pronunciate" on computers, and all spellcheck programs I have tried has flagged it as a typo.

Is "pronunciate" a word? Is it ok to use it in a sentence? This will probably come down to whether common usage has created this word. In you answer, please back yourself up with applicable evidence/proof.

Thanks!

Comment: Some words are just mistakes that became words. It's annoying. But that's what pretty much all words are right now. Your teacher should mark you down for using pronunciate though.

Comment: It is non-standard usage. If you want a (prescriptive) guide to standard American usage (in other words, a dictionary that will tell you what most people think is the "right" word to use in formal writing), the *American Heritage Dictionary* is a good resource. If you are looking for a _descriptive_ dictionary that will tell you what most people actually use, the Merriam-Webster family of dictionaries are good for non-scholarly uses, and the Oxford English Dictionary is best for serious research of usage. All three likely would not include "pronunciate."

Comment: *Pronunciate* is a word that has come into limited use due to a failure to properly hear or understand the word *enunciate*.

Comment: Could you supply a sample definition for *pronunciate*? I'm curious.

Comment: @TRiG edited. To pronounce is to make the sound of a word in the correct or a particular way.

Comment: Why not? Because _pronunciation_ is formed from the verb _pronounce,_ and it reduces the /aw/ vowel to /ə/ because the _-ation_ suffix shifts the stress to the next syllable. **Pronunciate* is a back-formation from _pronunciation_, but there appears to be no demand for another way to pronounce _pronounce,_ so it's simply not used. OK?

Comment: This looks like a (probably unintended) portmanteau of *pronounce* and *enunciate*. I can't imagine what it's intended to mean, though.

Comment: This is exactly like how *pronuncification* gives us both *pronuncificate* and *pronuncify*.

Comment: Much like **conversate,* it is a word in the sense that people use it.  Also much like **conversate,* it is usually used by mistake.

Comment: I would add *burglarize*, but that seems to be a genuine American form for *burgle*. Probably has the same sort of origin, though.

Comment: Note to the unwise: If someone uses any speech at all, it is valid linguistically. Linguists don't say that words don't exist if someone utters them. That said, it is not a standard word (in any variety of English). And it's the kind of thing that immediately identifies someone's level of education. That is just a fact.

Comment: The [full](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/152570?rskey=nXjWDp&result=3#eid) (subscription-only) OED does list the verb usage, but they say it's ***obsolete, rare*** (and the same for two *separate* entries for the ***adjectival*** usage).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As there is the verb *to pronounce* from French *prononcer* and Latin *pronuntiare*, there is no need to coin a second verb from *pronunciation*.

*To pronounce* has been in use for over 500 years, so a second and longer verb is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your research, it looks like many common dictionaries don’t contain that word.

You’re better off using *pronounce* instead of *pronunciate*.

Comment: I didn't say that it's not a word; I said that many common dictionaries don't consider it a word.

Comment: Ah but yes you did.  The OED considers many things words that it does not itself mention.  Therefore you cannot say that because a dictionary does not contain a word that it does not consider it a word.

Comment: "Ah but yes you did." - Eh, I don't agree with your view on what I said but there's really no point in us getting into an argument about it. "The OED considers many things words that it does not itself mention." - Fair enough; I've updated my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible that the word people are searching for when using the
>   term "pronunciate" and/or which may be preferable to the word
>   "pronounce" is **[enunciate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/enunciate)** which is defined on Dictionary.com as "[to]
>   say or pronounce clearly".

This answer was originally submitted as an edit and (rightly) rejected. However, @MalFunctionality, made a pertinent observation.

[@Marthaª](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169000/is-pronunciate-a-word/373137#comment351507_169000), in the comments, also said:

> This looks like a (probably unintended) portmanteau of *pronounce* and *enunciate*. I can't imagine what it's intended to mean, though